# Nested IF assistance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think the formula I need is a nested `If`:

I need to find the cells that contain country codes, and the formula I used worked for just 1 country code, but some cells contain multiple, eg:

CN, GB
CN, EG, IN, SY
NL, GB
KZ, RU, GB

I need to pick out all cells that contain, for example, GB or CN codes and return something like XY.

I was trying `=IF(OR(BE2="GB",BE2="CN"),"XY","-")` but this only brings back data if GB or CN are the only values in the cell

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: So would a value like "GB KZ, RU, SY NL" match your expected filter?

Comment: Try `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("GB",BE2)),ISNUMBER(FIND("CN",BE2))),"XY","-")`. If you would want to allow case-insensitivity i.e. `GB = gb`, `Cn = cN`, you could use `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GB",BE2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CN",BE2))),"XY","-")`.

Comment: Fab, Thank You!

Comment: @VBasic2008  You can combine `find_text` in an array constant, instead of separate formulas for each.  eg:  `=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND({"GB","CN"},BE2)))`

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A2,"*"&$C$2:$C$3&"*"),0)),"XY","-")`

If you list your country codes to search for in column C:C (and your data is in column A:A) you're able to expand or change the search values easily.
Enter this array-formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`.
[image]